# Determine all the extrema of a function subject to a non-linear constraint.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

**QUESTION**

Determine all extrema of the function

$$f(x,y) = x+ 2y $$ subject to $$x^2 + y^2 - 80 = 0$$

**ATTEMPT**

I don't think I understand what I'm supposed to do. This was in a test and I ended up trying to "graphically"or ïntuitively" find out how the $f(x,y)$ would behave in a circle of radius $\sqrt80$
Which left me with some pretty random numbers that turned out to also be wrong.

What could I have done differently? (If possible could I get a bit of a detailed explanation or some links to that info.)

Lagrange Multipliers: I tried that too on the paper and it also went horribly wrong (but I did get some points, though) but I couldn't quite figure it out.

Comment: Have you seen Lagrange multipliers?

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan I tried that too on the paper and it also went horribly wrong (but I did get some points).

Comment: @Siyanda made a mistake in my first version, corrected it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a usual problem for Lagrange multipliers. You define a Lagrange function via
$$L(x,y,\lambda)= x+2y + \lambda \cdot (x^2+y^2-80)$$
Now you look for critical points of the function $L$.

But here is the lagrange part more explicit. A critical point is a point where the gradient of $L$ is 
zero, as 
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial L}{\partial x} &= 1+ 2x\lambda \\
\frac{\partial L}{\partial y} &= 2+ 2y\lambda\\
\frac{\partial L}{\partial \lambda} &= x^2+y^2-80 
\end{align*}
we have to solve 
\begin{align*}
0&= 1+2x\lambda \\
0&= 2+2y \lambda \\
0&= x^2+y^2 -80
\end{align*}
Taking the first line times 2 we see that 
$$ 4 x \lambda = 2y \lambda, $$ 
and as $\lambda$ surely isn't $0$ we have 
$$y=2x.$$
Using this information in the third equation we have 
$$ 80 = x^2+ 4x^2 \iff 16=x^2$$
so you have to check $x=\pm 4$.

Via compactness you know one is a minimum and one is a maximum. So the one where $x$ (and hence $y$ ) is positive must be the maximum.

Comment: Oh, I see. That's slightly different from how the lecturer presented in it in class. Also...Thank you very much!

Comment: And I assume by "check it +/- 4" you mean I plug it back into the initial formula and determine the min/max of it (along with the y-value) accordingly?

Comment: @Siyanda well you are on a compact set, so one of them is the maximum and one is the minimum (if both are the same the function is constant), so in fact via the signs you don'T need to plug it into the function at all

Answer (score 0):

Your initial geometric attempt was good too.

The objective function has a gradient equal to (1,2), so the extrema will lie at the intersection between the circle of radius $\sqrt{80}$ and the line $y-2x=0$.

Substituting for $y$($=2x$) in $x^2+y^2=80$ yields $x=\pm4$.